# Using vector of different Objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

I am trying to make a vector of objects with different variables, can find how to access variables that are not in the base class.

```
struct X {
    string name;
 };

 struct Y : X {
    int num;
    void Set_Num(int a)
    {
       num = a;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
       vector<X*> v;
       v.push_back(new Y);
       v[0]->name="It"; //I can access name but not num
      // v[0]->Set_Num(10);
 }
```

Comment: you will have to cast it to a `Y`, but in C++ you have to be super careful.

Comment: What would you do, if the object was not in a vector?

Comment: If you store things as a base class and need to access specific derived parts, it's often a sign you need to redesign.

Comment: You can only access `X` members from a pointer to `X`. And `std::vector` doesn't magically change that.

Comment: What happens if you store an X object pointer, not Y ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, however there are a few things to consider.

In C++ you may do this by using either static_cast, dynamic_cast or reinterpret_cast.

`static_cast` will allow you to cast a base-pointer to a derived-pointer, but it is your responsibility to ensure that the cast is valid. If it is not you will get undefined results. For full rules see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

`dynamic_cast` functions will only allow casts that are valid and will return a `nullptr` if you try to cast a base-pointer to a derived-pointer when the object pointed to is not a subclass of derived. Use of dynamic_cast enables RTTI (RunTime-Type Identification) and will inject more code into your binary. (I.e. it has a cost.) For full rules see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

`reinterpret_cast` is even more liberal than static_cast and will allow you to compile even wild things like casting an int * to std::string* or whatever you like mostly. (There are a few things it will not do, but for pointers it is mostly a free game). For full rules see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

```
X* reallyY = new Y();
Y* y1 = static_cast<Y*>(reallyY);      // Ok 
Y* y2 = dynamic_cast<Y*>(reallyY);     // Ok
Y* y3 = reinterpret_cast<Y*>(reallyY); // Ok

X* reallyX = new X();
Y* y4 = static_cast<Y*>(reallyX);      // Undefined
Y* y5 = dynamic_cast<Y*>(reallyX);     // nullptr
Y* y6 = reinterpret_cast<Y*>(reallyX); // Undefined

int *intp = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reallyY); // Ok, reinterpret_cast may do this
Y* y7 = static_cast<Y*>(intp);      // Error, but not static cast.
Y* y8 = dynamic_cast<Y*>(intp);     // Error, Dynamic cast will also complain.
Y* y9 = reinterpret_cast<Y*>(intp); // Ok, reinterpret allows conversion back.

std::uintptr_t anInteger = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(reallyY); // OK.
```

These conversions will work whether the pointer is in a vector or not.

Comment: Not to mention [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)